# Unable to use HttpContext.Session.GetString()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, abstract-class

I want to use `HttpContext.Session.GetString()` to retrieve a session value inside a method which is supposed to return the CartId (I am making an ecommerce web application) for a particular user.

If I am trying to use `HttpContext.Session.GetString()` the code breaks and it gives me an error stating 'An object reference is needed for a non static method,object or property'.

Now how do you make an object of an abstract class? (`HttpContext` class is abstract)

Comment: Where in the stack are you trying to access `HttpContext`? You may need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to get an instantiated `HttpContext`

Comment: `HttpContext` is the class name, but it's also a controller property, leading to your error message. You'll need another way to obtain the current context.

Answer (score 0):

You could read this document related:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-session-state

If you want to retrieve a session value inside your controller,I think you don't need to make an object of Httpcontext ,just try as  the document

If you want to retrieve a session value outside your controller,add the codes in your startup:`services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`and inject the service into your target class and retrieve a session with `_accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("");`

The result:
[image]